# Windows Phone 8 C# Margin Thickness in array

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to set the margin of an ellipse with the value from an array. The code that I have so far is this:

```
    private void Dots()
    {
        string[] strArray = new string[] { "387,10,396,432"}; // this is the margin

        foreach (string str in strArray)
        {

            Ellipse a = new Ellipse();
            a.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
            a.Margin = new Thickness(Convert.ToInt32(str)); // the margin goes here
            a.Width = 25;
            a.Height = 25;
            a.Tap += DotTap;

            LevelPanel1.Children.Add(a);
        }
    }
```

The problem now is that i get the error "Input string is not in the correct format".
The margin should eventually look like this:

```
a.Margin = new Thickness(387,10,396,432);
```

Does anybody now how to fix this?
(p.s i'm new to coding in C#, so i'm sorry if this is a really stupid question.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just one String btw.

If you want to do it with a String[] then do this

```C#
string[] strArray = new string[] { "10","10","396","432" }; 
Thickness t = new Thickness(Convert.ToInt32(strArray[0]),
    Convert.ToInt32(strArray[1]),
    Convert.ToInt32(strArray[2]),
    Convert.ToInt32(strArray[3]));
```

Otherwise if you just want to do it with one String, split it with "," as a delimiter.

---

Example code of Split

```C#
string str = "387,10,396,432";
string[] strArray = str.Split(',');
Thickness t = new Thickness(Convert.ToInt32(strArray[0]),
    Convert.ToInt32(strArray[1]),
    Convert.ToInt32(strArray[2]),
    Convert.ToInt32(strArray[3]));
```

---

Example code for multiple margins

```
string[] strArray = new string[] { "387,10,396,432", "0,0,20,40" };

string[] first_margin = strArray[0].Split(',');
string[] second_margin = strArray[1].Split(',');

Thickness first_thickness = new Thickness(Convert.ToInt32(first_margin[0]),
    Convert.ToInt32(first_margin[1]),
    Convert.ToInt32(first_margin[2]),
    Convert.ToInt32(first_margin[3]));

Thickness second_thickness = new Thickness(Convert.ToInt32(second_margin[0]),
    Convert.ToInt32(second_margin[1]),
    Convert.ToInt32(second_margin[2]),
    Convert.ToInt32(second_margin[3]));
```

---

Example using your `for each`

```
string[] strArray = new string[] { "387,10,396,432", "0,0,20,40" };

foreach (string s in strArray)
{
    string[] margin = s.Split(',');

    Thickness thickness = new Thickness(Convert.ToInt32(margin[0]),
        Convert.ToInt32(margin[1]),
        Convert.ToInt32(margin[2]),
        Convert.ToInt32(margin[3]));


}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working, but how can i get this to work if i have multiple margins and not just one?

Comment: @NLGameVideosNL just do another split :), see updated solution.